# Problems installing jdk over OpenJdk on Ubuntu

Tags: openjdk, jdk

I tried to install JDK 21 on a machine with Ubuntu (last LTS) with a previous installation of OpenJDK 17.

I tried to remove the old one first with a mix of autoremove and purge (I do not remember the exact commands, I did it in a hurry) and launch the new installation from the terminal.

It did not work: if I check the version with `java -version`, I see the OpenJDK one. The pre-installed app to update software is not working anymore and if I try a `sudo apt-get upgrade` command the terminal says that it cannot find the jdk-21 package in the archive to re-install it (it was 17 before but after a try with the jdk-17 one the error message talks about the jdk-21).

These are the commands I used when the problem started, I used `history` to get them:

```
 1949  dpkg --configure -a
 1950  superus
 1951  dpkg --configure -a
 1952  sudo
 1953  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 1954  dpkg --congifure -a
 1955  clear
 1956  java -version
 1957  yum remove jdk17.0.10
 1958  sudo apt remove --purge openjdk*
 1959  apt autoremove openjdk*
 1960  sudo autoremove openjdk*
 1961  sudo apt autoremove openjdk*
 1962  java -version
 1963  sudo apt-get update
 1964  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1965  sudo apt-get autoremove
 1966  synaptic
 1967  sudo apt install synaptic
 1968  java -version
 1969  sudo apt-get update
 1970  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1971  exit
 1972  ls
 1973  cd Java
 1974  ls
 1975  tar jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
 1976  tar zxvf jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
 1977  java -version
 1978  sudo apt-get update
 1979  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1980  java -version
 1981  sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-17-jre
 1982  sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
 1983  exit
 1984  java -version
 1985  sudo apt-get update
 1986  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1987  sudo apt install default-jre
 1988  sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Please retrieve the exact commands using the history command and edit them into your question.